# Can an odd perfect number be a nontrivial multiple of a triangular number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers

(Note: This question has been cross-posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259181).)

Can an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) be a nontrivial multiple of a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)?

Comment: If the answer is yes, I think that nobody can give you an example.

Comment: @ajotatxe, how about if the answer is *NO*?

Comment: This is only to do feedback about it. We assume that there exists $m>1$ an integer such that, using the Eulerian form of an odd perfect number $N=P^{4\lambda+1}M^2$, then $$2P^{4\lambda+1}M^2=mn(n+1),$$
that is our non trivial triangle number is $m\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Then I believe that one can try analyse if it is possible deduce something, because one has $(P,M)=(n,n+1)=1$. If my calculations were rigths we can deduce also that $\sigma(mn(n+1))=3\cdot mn(n+1)$. On the other hand also one has Touchard's theorem to try do deductions ( if are feasibles in this question), dividing. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your observations, @user243301!  It is good to see more people getting interested in research on (odd) perfect numbers, ehh?  =)

Comment: I was thinking that if it ins't in the literature you can to study also the similar statement of this Steven Kahan, *Perfectly Odd Cubes*, Mathematics Magazine, Vol. 71, No. 2 (1998). I presume that you can read it with your MyJstor. What am I saying? That the first identity in the proof, here where the integer in RHS is your odd perfect number, seems that there is no problem when one do a comparison with Euler's theorem for OPN since being the $n$ in the identity odd, one can to take the second factor in such RHS as your Euler factor, and it is $=1mod4$, also our RHS is $=1mod4$.

Comment: I don't know nothing about the comparison of sizes between both factors in RHS, if we assume as was said that RHS is an OPN. The second factor also can has exponents $=1 mod 4$, see for example the toy example $97=97^1$. Thus I am saying that if it is interesting you can do the similar question that tell us the paper, but now for odd perfect numbers for an unknown integer $n$, and try to deduce if it is possible, that is if such assumption has mathematical meaning. Good luck.

Comment: @user243301, but is it even known that an odd perfect number is a sum of cubes?

Comment: I don't know nothing about it, if is well known or maybe is it's possible explain that it is interesting. What I am saying is that from my viewpoint is a similar question than this in your post, because you are asking if make sense that an OPN be a triangle number (a nontrivial multiple of a triangle number). I tried deduce an absurd by contradicition using Euler's theorem for OPN, and choosing the second factor as your Euler factor $q^{4λ+1}$ and thus the other factor as $m^2$ I can't deduce a contradition with the simple claims that I said, that is dividing by $4$, for an unknown odd $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turns out to be *YES*.

**Claim**

> If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number, then $N$ can be written in the form $$N = \dfrac{q(q+1)}{2}\cdot{d}$$
>   for some integer $d>1$.

**Proof**

By [Slowak's 1999 result](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/128884/MathSlov_49-1999-3_3.pdf), every odd perfect number must have the form
$$\dfrac{{q^k}\sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot{d'}$$
for some integer $d' > 1$.

If $k=1$, then our claim readily follows from Slowak's result.

Otherwise, if $k>1$, since $q \mid q^k$ and $(q + 1) \mid \sigma(q^k)$ for all $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then we have that every odd perfect number must have the form
$$\dfrac{q(q+1)}{2}\cdot{d''}$$
for some integer $d'' = ({q^{k-1}}{\sigma(q^k)}{d'})/(q+1) > 1$.

Comment: In fact, it is easy to show that, if $k=1$, then
$$d = D(n^2) = 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)$$
where $D(x)$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of the *positive integer* $x$.