# If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with $k > 1$ and $N = \frac{q(q+1)}{2} \cdot d$ for some $d > 1$, then what is $d$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

By this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2112125/28816), we know that every odd perfect number $N = q^k n^2$ can be written in the form
$$N = \dfrac{q(q+1)}{2} \cdot d$$
where $d > 1$.  (That is, an odd perfect number $N = q^k n^2$ is a nontrivial multiple of the triangular number
$$T(q) = \dfrac{q(q+1)}{2},$$
where $q$ is the *Euler prime* of $N$.)

If $k=1$, then it is easy to show that
$$d = D(n^2)$$
where $D(n^2) = 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)$ is the [*deficiency*](http://oeis.org/A033879) of the non-Euler part $n^2$.

Here is my question:

> If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with $k > 1$ and $N = \frac{q(q+1)}{2} \cdot d'$ for some $d' > 1$, then what is $d'$?

Comment: if you just setup the quadratic in q, you will get the condition for d' by requiring the discriminant D to be a square. if I am not mistaken, D=1+8N/d'. And this severely limits the possible values for d' since for all triangular numbers, 1+8N is a square.

Comment: @user25406, thank you for your comment.  Fleshing it out now into an actual answer with more details included.  I hope you do not mind!  =)

Comment: @user25406, I think your claimed result is trivial.  Please check out the answer that I have posted below.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. I meant that the only solutions are the trivial ones d'=N to get 1+8=3^2. I did say "severely limits the possible values" for d'.

Comment: Hold on.  Are you claiming that for all triangular numbers $N$, $1+8N$ is a perfect square?

Comment: yes, it is a known result.

Comment: I think I get your point now.

Comment: @user25406, note that it is not known if odd perfect numbers can be triangular (see e.g. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/234528).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more to the spirit of my expected answer for the original question, rather than the one presented in my other answer.

So we have an odd perfect number $N = q^k n^2 = {q(q+1)/2}\cdot{d'}$ (with $k>1$), where $d' > 1$ by [Slowak's 1999 result](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/128884/MathSlov_49-1999-3_3.pdf).

Thus, $\frac{2N}{q(q+1)} = \frac{\sigma(N)}{q(q+1)} = d'$, so that
$$d' = \dfrac{\sigma(n^2)\sigma(q^k)}{q(q+1)} = {q^{k-1}}\cdot{\dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}}\cdot{\dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{q+1}}.$$

Now, I have shown [elsewhere](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01868v2.pdf) that
$$\dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})},$$
so that we obtain
$$d' = {q^{k-1}}\cdot{\dfrac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})}}\cdot{\dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{q+1}}.$$
Finally, we have
$$d' = \bigg(\dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{\sigma(q)}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\dfrac{D(n^2)}{I(q^{k-1})}\bigg)$$
or equivalently,
$$d' = {q^{k-1}}\cdot\bigg(\dfrac{I(q^k)}{I(q)I(q^{k-1})}\bigg)\cdot{D(n^2)},$$
where $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ is the *abundancy index* of the (positive) integer $x$.

Note that these last two formulas reduce to the case $d = D(n^2)$ when $k=1$, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted by [user25406](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/25406) in a comment, setting up the quadratic in $q$, we obtain
$${d'}q^2 + {d'}q - 2N = 0.$$

In order for this equation to have (positive) integer solutions for $q$, we need the discriminant
$$D_1 := {d'}^2 + 8{d'}N$$
to be a perfect square.

This gives that
$$D_1 = {{d'}^2}\cdot(1 + 4q(q+1)) = \left({d'}(2q+1)\right)^2$$
is a perfect square, which is trivial.

**Added January 25 2017**

To clarify another comment, rewrite the equation
$${d'}q^2 + {d'}q - 2N = 0$$
as
$$q^2 + q - \dfrac{2N}{d'} = 0.$$

The discriminant is given by
$$D_2 := 1 + \dfrac{8N}{d'}.$$

user25406's (unproved) claim is that this is a perfect square only when $d' = N$.

Comment: unproved claim? when d'=N, D=1+8=3^2.

Comment: Yes, for $d'=N$, the discriminant $D_2$ is a perfect square.  But are you sure that $d'=N$ is the only value of $d'$ that makes $D_2$ a perfect square?  Note that, per Ochem and Rao's result on a lower bound for the magnitude of an odd perfect number, $N > {10}^{1500}$.

Comment: It's not difficult to find values of d' that are not equal to N but make D a perfect square. Any d=T/N will do where T is any triangular number not necessarily equal to N so that we end up with 1+8T=s^2.

Comment: @user25406, my point in the initial version of my answer was that:  Given the discriminant $D_2 = 1 + (8N/d')$, if you substitute $N = {q(q+1)/2}\cdot{d'}$, you get $D_2 = 1 + 4q(q+1) = (2q+1)^2$, which is indeed a perfect square.  Note that this value for the discriminant no longer depends on $N$ or $d'$, but only on the value of $q$.

Comment: Any way, the reason why I am highly skeptical about your (claimed) proof for $d' = N$ is that it will imply $q = 1$, which would contradict the fact that $q$ is the Euler prime (that is, $q$ is a prime number and ought to satisfy $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$).  I invite you to write out your complete proof for $d' = N$, as it will prove the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture on odd perfect numbers (that is, that $k=1$ ought to hold).

Comment: So if I let $d' = N/T$ where $T=m(m+1)/2$ (say), then
$$D_2 = 1 + \dfrac{8N}{d'} = 1 + 8T = s^2$$
indeed holds.

Comment: Effectively, $T=q(q+1)/2$ from the set of equations.  Which brings us back to my original point.  We are going around in circles here.

Comment: So I guess my challenge question to you now is:  Can you produce an integer $r \neq q$ such that
$$N = q^k n^2 = \frac{r(r+1)}{2}\cdot{\overline{d}}$$
is an odd perfect number for some integer $\overline{d} > 1$>